# How do I pass the Post Item ID into getInitialProps?

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I'm new to Next.js and having trouble getting a post ID to pass from the index page to the post page getInitialProps() function. The pages are being requested with the Link component.

The end goal is to get the post ID into the post.js getInitialProps function so that the correct json file will be requested like:

https://www.example.com/menu/100.json   <- id = 100

The JSON API endpoints are all working correctly from the browser and the index page is working in nextjs.

So far, I've tried several print statements to look for where this Link href property is being passed, but I've not yet been able to access the "itemid" in the href.

There are 3 main files to reproduce this:

index.js

```
import Layout from '../components/MyLayout.js'
import Link from 'next/link'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

const Index = (props) => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>Pages</h1>
    <ul>
{props.results.map(result => (
        <li key={result.id}>
          <Link as={`/${result.slug}`} href={`/post?itemid=${result.id}`}>
            <a>{result.title}</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </Layout>
)

Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
  const res = await fetch('https://www.example.com/menu.json')
  const data = await res.json()

  return {
    results: data['data'].map(data => data)
  }
}

export default Index
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express()

    server.get('/:id*', (req, res) => {
      const actualPage = '/post'
      const queryParams = { slug: req.params.id + req.params[0]}
      app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
    })


    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res)
    })

    server.listen(3000, err => {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
    })
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.error(ex.stack)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

post.js

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'
import Layout from '../components/MyLayout.js'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

const Post = props => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>{props.result.title}</h1>
    <p>{props.result.bodyCopy.replace(/<[/]?p>/g, '')}</p>
    <img src={props.result.image} />
  </Layout>
)

Post.getInitialProps = async function(context) {
  const { itemid } = context.query

  const res = await fetch(`https://www.example.com/menu/${itemid}.json`)
  const result = await res.json()

  return { result }
}

export default withRouter(Post)
```

Here's what I'd like to happen:

User requests:  https://www.example.com/some-page
"some-page" has a Post ID of 100

The server gets both "some-page" and "100" on the page being requested/refreshed.

The server makes an API call to: https://www.example.com/menu/100.json

So far, the best result I've got was to get the API url to be:

https://www.example.com/menu/some-page.json

This endpoint is invalid since it is not being requested by the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Please try if this is working as what you have expected?

Index.js

```js
import Layout from '../components/MyLayout.js'
import Link from 'next/link'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

const Index = (props) => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>Pages</h1>
    <ul>
{props.results.map(result => (
        <li key={result.id}>
          <Link as={`/${result.slug}/${result.id}`} href={`/post?itemid=${result.id}`}>
            <a>{result.title}</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </Layout>
)

Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
  const res = await fetch('https://www.example.com/menu.json')
  const data = await res.json()

  return {
    results: data['data'].map(data => data)
  }
}

export default Index
```

Server.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express()

    server.get('/:slug/:id*', (req, res) => {
      const actualPage = '/post'
      const queryParams = { slug: req.params.slug, itemid: req.params.id }
      app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
    })


    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res)
    })

    server.listen(3000, err => {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
    })
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.error(ex.stack)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

Post.js

```js
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'
import Layout from '../components/MyLayout.js'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

const Post = props => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>{props.result.title}</h1>
    <p>{props.result.bodyCopy.replace(/<[/]?p>/g, '')}</p>
    <img src={props.result.image} />
  </Layout>
)

Post.getInitialProps = async function(context) {
  const { itemid } = context.query

  const res = await fetch(`https://www.example.com/menu/${itemid}.json`)
  const result = await res.json()

  return { result }
}

export default withRouter(Post)
```